# Center text right side from image in header

Tags: html, css, text, center

[This](http://tvitre.org/EP/sunmissive/) is the site that i've been coding all day but i cant get the text on the right side of the logo to be in the center of the logo.

Can anyone help, i tried looking for an answer but did not find one.?

This is the CSS

```
/*
    Name: SunMissive
    Date: 13, 07, 2013
    Discription: Responsive Html5 And css3 site
    Version: 1.0
    Auther: David Kvindesland
    Auther URL: http://www.tvitre.org
*/

body {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/5exXQso.png");
    color: #000305;
    font-size: 87.5%; /*base font size is 14px */
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, 'lucida sans unicode';
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'pacificoregular';
    src: url('pacificothingk.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {

}

a:hover, a:active{

}

.body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    clear: both;    
}

.mainheader img {
    width: auto;
    height: 30%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 2% 0%;
}

.mainheader span {
    text-align;
    font-size: 500%; 
    font-style: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: pacificoregular;
}

.mainheader nav {
    background-color: #9C9C9C;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainheader nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.mainheader nav ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;
}

.mainheader nav a:hover, .mainheader nav a:active,
.mainheader nav .active a:link, .mainheader nav .active a:visited {
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #4F9BE8;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.mainheader nav li a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainContent {
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.content: {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

.topcontent {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin: 2%;
}

.bottomcontent {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin: 2%;

}

.mainfooter {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 2%;
    text-align: center

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="NO">

<head>
    <title>SunMissive</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

</head>

<body class="body">

    <header class="mainheader">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/M8lrFtm.gif" alt="tvitre logo"/>
        <span>SunMissive.no</span>

        <nav><ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Why</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </nav></ul>
    </header>

    <div class="mainContent">
        <div class="content">
            <article class="topcontent">
                <header>
                    <h2><a href="#" title="first post">Viderutviklet Design</a></h2>
                </header>

                <footer>
                    <p class="post-info">Dette inlegget er skrevet av David 12.07.2013</p>
                </footer>

                <content>
                    <p>
                        Denne siden er bare laget som demo, den er av mitt eget arbeid og du kan derfor ikke bruke den videre. takk. Aliquam congue faucibus. Donec non mi eu risus vehicula accumsan sed nec nunc. Pellentesque malesuada tellus in consectetur laoreet. Donec volutpat adipiscing blandit. Praesent in vestibulum turpis. Praesent pulvinar semper nulla, a imperdiet ligula auctor quis. Fusce tempor sodales dignissim. Aenean lobortis sapien blandit blandit laoreet. Quisque et purus iaculis massa tempus imperdiet. Aliquam accumsan tristique ipsum, id euismod elit convallis ut. Nullam lobortis elit lorem.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        c sed viverra orci. Suspendisse sed diam quam. Praesent in lacus nec enim euismod posuere eget sit amet orci. In sed viverra turpis, at sagittis sapien. Fusce aliquam turpis et sapien tristique commodo id in arcu. Praesent feugiat lectus ligula, quis condimentum felis pharetra vel. Fusce rutrum commodo gravida. Praesent vel consectetur dolor. Mauris eu tempor nisi. Vestibulum id eros vel est vulputate interdum. Quisque a ipsum malesuada, mollis metus id, lacinia odio. Suspendisse egestas felis non nisi faucibus, sit amet euismod lorem congue. Pellentesque tempor odio ac dapibus vehicula.
                    </p>
                </content>
            </article>

            <article class="bottomcontent">
                <header>
                    <h2><a href="#" title="second post">Her kommer det mer!</a></h2>
                </header>

                <footer>
                    <p class="post-info">Dette inlegget er skrevet av David 10.07.2013</p>
                </footer>

                <content>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam aliquam congue faucibus. Donec non mi eu risus vehicula accumsan sed nec nunc. Pellentesque malesuada tellus in consectetur laoreet. Donec volutpat adipiscing blandit. Praesent in vestibulum turpis. Praesent pulvinar semper nulla, a imperdiet ligula auctor quis. Fusce tempor sodales dignissim. Aenean lobortis sapien blandit blandit laoreet. Quisque et purus iaculis massa tempus imperdiet. Aliquam accumsan tristique ipsum, id euismod elit convallis ut. Nullam lobortis elit lorem.
                    </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="mainfooter">
        <p>&copy; David Kvindesland - 2013 - webmaster@tvitre.org</p>
    </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following styles to make this work. They are currently inline, but placing them in your CSS should do the trick:

```
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/M8lrFtm.gif" alt="tvitre logo" style="float:left;">
    <span style="display: block;position: relative;top: 45px;">SunMissive.no</span>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Alternatively, this is a good resource for vertically centering text. [Link](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)

Comment: thanks! it worked. :D but may i ask why you have the div? (Very new to html)

Comment: If you don't use that div, the divs beneath that header will also take the float into account and try to float around the header so you'll get a few styling errors (test it out for a better visual). If you could mark me as a helpful answer, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Im sorry i dont have a good enugh reputation (i did try) But again thank you!